# Range of number of linearly independent solutions of an $m\times n$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, solution-verification

Suppose we have a linear map $A\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{F})$ - i.e. a linear map from $\mathbb{F}^m$ to $\mathbb{F}^n$, where $m\le n$.What are the largest and smallest possible numbers of linearly independent solutions?

Attempt: We basically want to find what values $null (A)$ can take. If the rank is 1 then $null(A)=n-1$. But I'm not sure how to find the other bound...

Comment: Your attempt is incorrect. If the rank of $A$ is $1$, then $\operatorname{null}(A) = n-1$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann indeed, I have corrected this. Thanks for pointing this out. Any ideas how to approach the second part?

Comment: Well actually your upper bound is also incorrect: if $A = 0$, then the rank of $A$ could be $0$, which gives an upper bound of $n$. For the lower bound, note that the largest possible rank of $A$ is $m$.